# Push up notifications using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, onclick, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an project and I am using firebase 
I want to make a button when a user pressing it sent an notification to all users automatically.
I can't find anything like this.
I want any code can do this.

Please save my life guys.

Comment: That is a bit too broad of a topic for a question on Stack Overflow. But I highly recommend reading this blog post on the topic: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will need to subscribe every client to the same topic and after send a push to said topic.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple?authuser=0

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to fetch all the register device token from the firebase.

Then you need to create JSON Object :

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
 json.put("to",/* device tooken*/);
 json.put("use to","/topics/all");
 json.put("notification",/* notifications Messgae */);
```

After that, you need to hit the API call on the below-given URL. You can use volley, Retrofit or something else in which you are comfortable

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

But you need to add the headers with the API call which is mandatory:

**"Authorization", /*SERVER_KEY*/

   "Content-Type","application/json";**

For more clarification, Look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message).

It works for you.